# Does Device Owner app get System App permissions?

Tags: android, device-owner

I'm trying to put some pieces together regarding the Device Owner application.

With regards the the newly released [EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/), is there a way for the Device Owner application get system app permissions? I have noticed that the API allows remote package installation, but for this to work, the application needs to have [INSTAL_PACKAGES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES) permissions (reserved for system apps).

Also, is there any official documentation to the Android Hidden API, or is it all just code inspection and comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Device Owner does not have system app permissions.

On Marshmallow a Device Owner can call `PackageInstaller` and silently install apps.

The TestDPC basically shows all the features you can implement:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc

For some more interesting info:
https://florent-dupont.blogspot.ca/2015/02/10-things-to-know-about-device-owner.html

Comment: Indeed the TestDPC is a great example. I too have encountered it while reading through the EMM API. Also thanks for the blog link, looks neat.